# d3 js - how to mimic distance/depth of field using randomized opacity on fillStyle() & fillRect() without strobe effect?

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

I am attempting to use particlesDepthBlur() in place of the opacity for the "snowflakes" - which is located inside the step function, however it produces an undesired strobe effect - why? Consider the following code,

Edited for clarification:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var num = 2000;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var width = canvas.width = 960;
var height = canvas.height = 500;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var particles = d3.range(num).map(function(i) {
  return [Math.round(width*Math.random()), Math.round(height*Math.random())];
});

function particlesDepthBlur(){ 
   return Math.random();
   console.log(Math.random());
}

function particlesDepthSize(){
   return Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
}

d3.timer(step);

function step() {
  ctx.shadowBlur=0;
  ctx.shadowColor="";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,"+particlesDepthBlur()+")";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
  ctx.shadowBlur=particlesDepthSize();
  ctx.shadowColor="white";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
  particles.forEach(function(p) {
    p[0] += Math.round(2*Math.random()-1);
    p[1] += Math.round(2*Math.random()-1) + 2;
    if (p[0] < 0) p[0] = width;
    if (p[0] > width) p[0] = 0;
    if (p[1] < 0) p[1] = height;
    if (p[1] > height) p[1] = 0;
    drawPoint(p);
  });
};

function drawPoint(p) {
  ctx.fillRect(p[0],p[1],1,1);
};
</script>
<style>
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: Is the effect you are referring to tied to all of the particles getting the same value for shadowBlur each step? This causes them to all have the blur and then all not to have the blur.

Comment: try again I just updated the code to make sense!

Comment: Plato, in `drawPoint` change the last two 1s to 5s or 10s in `fillRect` and the strobe effect can be seen.

Comment: That isn't it Jason, fillStyle opacity param just has to be randomized.  recheck code i updated with proper code sample

Comment: Interestingly enough, the blur/shadow actually minimizes the horrid effects on the eyes, but yeah I'd still like to apply an opacity to each "snowflake"/rectangle and have it not fluctuate, or only ever so slightly (to look like a snowflake, not a bad flashback)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things:
Firstly you are calling `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,"+particlesDepthBlur()+")";` immediately before filling the background of the canvas.
Second, you are only calculating the blur and opacity once per frame, not per particle.
Thirdly, if you calculate it per particle (and continue to use `Math.random()`) then it bogs down my machine with several thousand operations per second.

Here is my

## *[fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/njCMf/11/)*

~Every frame I calculate 10 opacities and 10 sizes and iterate across the particles setting them per particle.~ << This was an 
[old version](http://jsfiddle.net/njCMf/5/); now the opacities are all set up before `step()` is called, and the sizes are proportional to opacities.

edit: good job with the random falling-downward motion!
edit2: tweaking to set constant opacity and size per particle. this still runs very slowly for me, probably because you are running Math.random() 4000 times per frame. You might consider calculating a couple dozen positional vectors once per frame, and iterate across all your particles. This way every *n* snowflakes would be falling in the same pattern, at the benefit of much less computation needed.

Finally, perhaps consider making the 'close' snowflakes (big and bright) fall faster than the 'far' snowflakes.

```
<snip>
// Set up an opacity value for each particle, this will later be indexed with j
var particleOpacities = [];
particles.forEach(function(p){
  particleOpacities.push(particlesDepthBlur());
});

d3.timer(step);
var j = 0;
// since j is used by both step and drawPoint, it has to be outside both functions
function step() {
  ctx.shadowBlur=0;
  ctx.shadowColor="";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
  j = 0;
  particles.forEach(function(p) {
    p[0] += Math.round(2*Math.random()-1);
    p[1] += Math.round(2*Math.random()-1) + 2;
    if (p[0] < 0) p[0] = width;
    if (p[0] > width) p[0] = 0;
    if (p[1] < 0) p[1] = height;
    if (p[1] > height) p[1] = 0;
    drawPoint(p);
  });
};

function drawPoint(p) {
  j++; // iterate over points
  var particleSize = particleOpacities[j] * 4;
  ctx.shadowBlur=particleSize;
  ctx.shadowColor="white";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + particleOpacities[j] + ")";
  ctx.fillRect(p[0],p[1],particleSize,particleSize);
};
```

Comment: Can we not set the opacity per-snowflake, before ever running step()?

Comment: Not if you want to change the opacity over steps. *edit* - sorry I just realized I misread your comment: "I'd still like to apply an opacity to each "snowflake"/rectangle and have it **not** fluctuate"; you can certainly set it once per particle

Answer (score 2):

The `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,"+particlesDepthBlur()+")";` randomly changes how much of the previous canvas is visible. It does so uniformly across the entire canvas. Sometimes if fills the screen completely with black wiping out the past views, other times it lets the last screen partially show. When it lets previous views be seen it can as much double the amount of white on the canvas, and when followed by a low opacity suddenly the quantity of white drops.

```
function particlesDepthBlur(){ 
   return Math.random(0.5)+.5;
}
```

smooths this out